# What's the most effecient hosting solution for running multiple Pyramid (Python) websites?

Tags: vps, python, shared-hosting, mod-wsgi

In the past, I've written websites in two languages. PHP for smaller sites and Python for larger sites. With this setup, I would run multiple Paster instances to serve each site on a different port and then use nginx to proxy to Paster. This worked fine.

However, I no longer wish to use PHP for smaller sites. I want to use Python. This means the server could be running more than ~50 websites, for example. At this point, it seems silly to be running 50 instances of Paster on 50 different ports.

What's the best alternative here?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, while paster is great for hosting low-level or small sites, the fact that Python's ability to use multithreading (due to the GIL) means that you're essentially limiting how quickly paster can respond.

Paster is just a WSGI server, and what you're looking for is another server that circumvents this restriction.  Graham Dumpleton's [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is a great (and as far as I know, only) WSGI server that runs through Apache, which means you can use your normal methods for hosting web sites.  Configuration is very simple, and the site includes an example for [configuring Pylons](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithPylons), of which Pyramid is its spiritual successor.

If worse comes to worst, the mailing list is a treasure trove of information, and you can expect answers to your questions extremely quickly.

Hope this gets you on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

You should give [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) a try. We use on our servers with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), and IMHO is one the best way to deploy WSGI apps. It is a bit scary (lot of options) to configure at first, but it's a very powerful application server.